# Two javascript "actions" inside one function in two different pages

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to modify several selectboxes using the following code in a custom.js file. Each ID is in different pages and the code that I'm using in footer.php is the following:

```
<script>
    var selectFunction = function() {
    document.getElementById('ofae').options[0].text = 'Artists';
    };
    var selectFunctionn = function() {
    document.getElementById('ofav').options[0].text = 'Artists';
    }; 
</script>
```

Then:

```
<?php
    // without if statement
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">  $(function(){  selectFunction();selectFunctionn(); }); </script>';
    ?>
```

The problem is that only one of them get executed, when I'm in page 2 and the first value is NULL it doesn't execute the rest of the code.

Comment: Read the error console. It is possible there was an error. If the function is called at all it will run *all* the code inside it .. unless it is abnormally terminated, as with an exception. So the likely cases are 1) it did make the change, which was subsequently undone or not observed; or 2) it failed to run correctly and the change was not made (eg. there is no appropriate '#ofae' element). I bet 1 stackoverflow-reputation on it being #2 .. and a case of "why isn't this code working?"

Comment: My goodness. If going to up-vote such questions, please at least demand a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify your function like this and it will work

```
var selectFunction = function() {
    if(document.getElementById('ofae') != null){
         document.getElementById('ofae').options[0].text = 'Artists';
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('ofav') != null){
         document.getElementById('ofav').options[0].text = 'Artists';
    }
};
```

I hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

A test file test.php with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test php echo script</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="ofav">
            <option value="">o1</option>
            <option value="">o2</option>
            <option value="">o3</option>
            <option value="">o4</option>
            <option value="">o5</option>
        </select>
        <select id="ofae">
            <option value="">o1</option>
            <option value="">o2</option>
            <option value="">o3</option>
            <option value="">o4</option>
            <option value="">o5</option>
        </select>
        <script>
        var selectFunction = function() {
        document.getElementById('ofav').options[0].text = 'Artists';
        document.getElementById('ofae').options[0].text = 'Artists';
        }
        </script>
        <?php
        // without if statement
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">  $(function(){  selectFunction();  }); </script>';
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

works fine!

Check:

- if there are no typing errors
- if PHP if statement is correct
- if there are two `<select>` blocks
- ...

Comment: It doesn't work, only affects the first getElementById. I revised the code and maybe the reason is becaouse the two ID's are on different pages, not in the same. But still don't know how to make it work.

Comment: If you have two different pages, you have to input the the code twice. Can you make a plunker of your pages with the relevant code!? And a question update to see what exactly you mean.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, I've updated the question with the new info. and the websites URL's.

Comment: Here http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue you can create files to reproduce the complete scenario with pages and the relevant code. Save it and send it here as a comment to see what exactly you mean.